# Whats is the correct way to implement FXM generated script

Tags: tracking, javascript, fxm

I'm having a problem implementing FXM generated script on some of out sites.

The Issue, I found is that, the generated **Tracking script** script is located on our CMS, which is not a public domain.

I tried downloading the script and deminify it and saw the domain hard coded inside of it.

```
SCBeacon = new SCBeacon("//cms.xxxx.com/sitecore/api/ssc/Beacon/Service");
```

Is there other way to do this without making the CMS domain public=?
Can the script be downloaded and changed to point to the CD server which is available to public?

Will appreciate much if you share how to properly implement this.

Answer (score 4):

In a distributed environment, you must enable the following two configuration files on all the servers:

**Sitecore.FXM.Bundle.config**

**Sitecore.FXM.config**

Also, make sure that the following configuration files are enabled on your content management servers:

**Sitecore.FXM.Speak.config**

**Search configs (lucene files or solr files)**

In addition, on each content management server, you must specify which content delivery server that the content management server should use.

In the Sitecore.FXM.config file, in the FXMHostname setting, specify the content delivery server:

```
<setting name="FXM.Hostname" value="yourdomain" />
```

Use patching files to change this setting.
This parameter is empty by default.

**Reference:**
[Configuring FXM](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/82/digital_marketing/federated_experience_manager/configuring/configuring_fxm)

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `FXM.Hostname` setting to a hostname that is handled by your CD server. Use a config patch like this:

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <settings>
      <setting name="FXM.Hostname">
        <patch:attribute name="value">mydomain.com</patch:attribute>
      </setting>
    </settings>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```